# Can I swap out Nvidia cards without having to reconfigure the drivers?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda

Currently running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on my desktop with a GTX 650 **with drivers version 352.63, CUDA 7.5, cuDNN, Digits, Tensorflow.

I would like to get a GTX 1060 card.

Would it be just a matter of powering down, swapping the cards and booting up again; will the driver recognize the card?

Comment: Can you confirm the driver version?

Comment: Nvidia driver 352.63

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally this works, except in this case you will need newer drivers than what is in Ubuntu for the GTX 1060, which was released after Ubuntu 14.04.

1. First, [update your Nvidia drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers) to the latest version:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa   
   sudo apt-get update   
   sudo apt-get upgrade   
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-370
   ```

   Then reboot.
2. After you've installed `nvidia-370` you can safely just power the machine off and swap out the card.

Comment: Thanks. But would the 370 driver be still compatible with CUDA 7.5?

Comment: Oh that is a good question, I am unsure, perhaps ask that as a new question and I can start investigating?